JSONObject as postapi param in java Springboot
This is my post API which takes jsonObject as param, I am trying to test it via postman I did all config in it like content-type: application/json
@PostMapping("/saveUser")
public void saveSingleUser(@RequestBody JSONObject jsonObject) {
    // code block
}

I also did:
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

in my API, but when I print it after these lines of my code block in my API I get empty json {} as I print why so? I don't want to set java object as my API param I also have few json dependencies in my Gradle build file.
My main problem is: First I used to set json same as my user POJO but now I'm adding a other table's field that is role field so therefore a custom json is going to my api but it seems empty when it comes to my API.
I tried adding dependencies by asking same to ChatGPT, phind but it wasn't much helpful tho. I'm expecting to see a the custom JSON I sent from postman.

@SanjayChoudhary Did you mean Content-Type?

@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class TodoRest {

@SanjayChoudhary @Consumes is not a Spring annotation. What are you trying to say?

import jakarta.ws.rs.Consumes; its jakartaee 8 specification.

@SanjayChoudhary Sure, but what does that have to do with this question and your first comment?

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-set-json-content-type

@SanjayChoudhary I don't know what you're trying to say at this point. Going back to your first comment, the Accept request header is meant to indicate what media types the client is able to handle (influences the server's HTTP response). It has nothing to do with the content of the request itself and therefore isn't relevant to the question here, where the @RequestBody isn't parsing the request content as expected by the author of the question.

@Sotirios I did not understand question correctly so yes that comment is irrelevent but now I am talking about that rest endpoint is able to handle json data @RequestMapping(value = "/greetings", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json")

@SanjayChoudhary The consumes element on the @RequestMapper is not necessary. When you have no consumes, Spring MVC will accept everything, deferring to the HandlerMethodArgumentResolver used for the handler method arguments. It's up to that whether it can deserialize the request content. Assuming the OP has Jackson on the classpath, that'll be MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter which does support application/json.

You have to use Map<String, Object> as request body which is same as JSONObject at the functional level. Your request body will be automatically mapped to this Object. Or you have to use String as request body type and parse it to JSON using libraries like Jackson.
@PostMapping("/saveUser")
public void saveSingleUser(@RequestBody Map<String,Object> jsonObject) {
    // code block
}


The thing that performs the JSON deserializes is likely Jackson. If you're using Jackson, you might as well use its strongly typed JSON API, ie. ObjectNode.
